# How to pretend I am using Windows or Android in Browser settings

Tags: macos, security, microsoft-outlook, vpn, android

I've got a link to login into my work outlook mailbox via browser outside of the work campus - it looks like https://vpn...blablabla.

I am able to login via Opera on Android phone, but when I try to login via MacOS the site does not proceed saying that my OS is MacOS and it is filtered out. I use only Mac thus it is very inconvenient limitation.

Is there a way (without installing Windows on Mac) to pretend I am using Windows or Android in order to bypass this strange limitation?

Comment: You can spoof your browser fingerprint, but your OS is another matter.  Do you know why it's blocked?  For example, if there is some form of compatibility issue, spoofing another OS won't fix the problem.  If it's a security issue, you could get into trouble trying to defeat the controls.  It might be worth discussing the problem with your IT people and let them suggest the best solution.

Comment: Every browser these days support development / debug mode and can emulate mobile devices too. You can try [opera mobile emulator](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mobile-emulator/) and check if it works for you. Still, as suggested by @fixer1234, it is recommended to discuss it with IT team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Chrome, open the DevTools pane/window (press <kbd>F12</kbd>). Click the menu button (three dots, arranged vertically) in the upper right. Choose "More tools" > "Network conditions". Scroll down to "User agent". Uncheck "Select automatically", and you are free to choose the OS and browser that will be reported to the page. This only takes effect within the tab you were viewing when you opened DevTools.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398103/how-user-agent-in-network-conditions-tab-works) has an image of what the Network Conditions tab looks like:

[image]